# Replace WebActivator PreApplicationStartMethod with OwinStartupAttribute?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, owin, webactivator

I'm using `WebActivator.PreApplicationStartMethod` in my current project but it seems like the `OwinStartupAttribute` could do the same job? Is this the proper use of the `OwinStartupAttribute`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`PreApplicationStartMethodAttribute` allows you to run some code early in the ASP.NET pipeline. ASP.NET requests are handled by the IIS pipeline.

Owin middleware is designed to run in a server-agnostic pipeline.
You could host owin middleware in a non-IIS environment, basically.

If you want to run Owin through the IIS pipeline you have to install and use `Owin.Host.SystemWeb`:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb
```

and it seems that **SystemWeb** [uses](http://katanaproject.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb/PreApplicationStart.cs) **PreApplicationStartMethod** to hook into the application startup.

So, I guess, there not much difference at the moment.

I would stick to Owin **Startup** considering things might change in the future.

I have found a great explanation [here](http://edgamat.com/2014/06/using-owin-to-build-a-clean-asp-net-mvc-startup/) and [these](http://www.asp.net/aspnet/overview/owin-and-katana/owin-startup-class-detection) [articles](http://www.asp.net/aspnet/overview/owin-and-katana/owin-middleware-in-the-iis-integrated-pipeline) are worth reading.

Comment: In my application WebActivator.PreApplicationStartMethod runs before Application_Start() but OwinStarup runs after Application_Start() so it does not seem to replace WebActivator?

Comment: @Marcus: You're right. Owin startup should, in fact, replace Application_Start.